# original copies

Tags: word-choice, phrase-requests

I want to ask someone to give me 2 copies of a letter but I don't mean photocopying it I mean two letters which both of them contain original signature and stamp, how should I say that in a letter so that he doesn't confuse what I want with 2 photocopies?

*I wanted to have 2 copies of this letter*

or

*I wanted to have 2 of original copies of  this letter*

or

*something else*

Comment: Two wet-ink signed copies or two original/authentic copies.

Comment: Although not recommended, I’ve heard the term “original duplicate/copy” used before when dealing with federal (US) government contracts. Often two or three copies of a contract are drawn up and each one is signed by both parties. One original goes to the contractor, one goes to government contracting office, and sometimes a third goes to the government financial folks as often funding is attached to the contracts (but mostly it’s to have a second original around in case the other one gets lost). All hail bureaucracy.

Answer (score 1):

Be as specific as possible.  I have received such letters (USA) and the wording goes along the lines of "...two original copies with original (not machine) signatures on each..."

It is fun to observe that the oxymoron "original copy" is in standard use, to distinguish from photocopies and the like.

Answer (score 1):

*Hand-signed* is pretty clear, and not uncommon (many Google hits are autographed items being sold, but there are plenty of more relevant items).  It would take a bit of effort to misunderstand "Two hand-signed and stamped copies"

Answer (score 1):

I would ask for "Two hand-signed and stamped originals of the letter."